# Show text portion in instead of numerical of enum in column

Tags: c#, .net, enums, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I am using infragistic's ultragrid and I want to show the text portion of a enum property.  I tried doing it like so

```
private void MapToLevel()
{
   foreach (var row in HistoryGrid.Rows)
    {
       row.Cells["LevelId"].Value = row.Cells["LevelId"].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

this doesn't change anything.

this method is being called here

```
public new void Refresh()
 {
    LoadData();
    HistoryGrid.DataSource = null;
    HistoryGrid.DataSource = _BindingSource;
    HistoryGrid.DataBind();
    MapToLevel();
}

private void LoadData()
{
   _histories = _controller.GetAll(_personId, _companyId);
   _BindingSource = new BindingSource { DataSource = _histories };
}
```

Comment: Did you ask on the Infragistics forums?

Comment: @WillemvanRumpt Yep, they are slow to respond as usual

Comment: Okidoke :) 
I just can't stop myself from asking everytime I see a question of the "...I'm using <insert component vendor>, and want to..." persuasion :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to get the name of the enum:

```
row.Cells["LevelId"].Value = Enum.GetName(typeof(YourEnum), row.Cells["LevelId"]);
```

Comment: I'm trying your way but it's not allowing me to parse,convert, or cast the the current value(a string) to int32.

Comment: @atbyrd what's the value of row.Cells["LevelId"].Value, "1" or "EnumName"?

Comment: actually its not your suggestion creating the error. The grid is expecting int32 but I'm giving it a string

Answer (score 4):

This is an UltraGridColumn extension that transform an enum in a ValueList

```
public static ValueList ToValueList(this UltraGridColumn cl, string vlKey, Type t)
{
    ValueList vl = new ValueList();
    if (vlKey != string.Empty) vl.Key = vlKey;
    if (t.IsEnum == true)
    {
        // Get enum names
        string[] names = Enum.GetNames(t);
        Array a = Enum.GetValues(t);

        int i = 0;
        foreach (string s in names)
            vl.ValueListItems.Add(a.GetValue(i++), s.Replace("_", " "));
    }
    cl.Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.DropDownList;
    return vl;
}
```

You call it in the InitializeLayout event of your UltraWinGrid for the proper column

```
UltraGridColum cl = e.Layout.Bands[0].Columns["Gender"];
cl.ValueList = cl.ToValueList("gender_list", typeof(GenderEnum));
```

having a GenderEnum defined as:

```
public enum GenderEnum
{
    Female = 0,
    Male = 1
}
```

Of course I'm supposing that your datasource contains a column with the corresponding values of your enum. (In my case I have a column Gender with values 0 and 1)

Answer (score 1):

Try explicit casting:

```
private void MapToLevel()
{
   foreach (var row in HistoryGrid.Rows)
    {
       row.Cells["LevelId"].Value = ((myEnumType)row.Cells["LevelId"].Value).ToString();
    }
}
```